# Create local copy of a file when editing and saving on remote server using VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VS code to access cpp files on a remote server. I open and edit the files on the remote server using VS code. Every time I edit and save a file on the remote server, I want VS code to create the same copy on the local machine (which will be a backup if remote goes bad). Can it be done? I dont want to copy each file separately using 'scp'.

Comment: ever heard of rsync or sftp?